# Redshift to BigQuery using Apache Beam Dataflow

Tags: python, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to migration 1 TB Data from Amazon Redshift to BigQuery using Dataflow?
Can I using apache beam (python) to migration from Amazon Redshift to BigQuery?
If can using apache beam, how migration process (code) from Amazon Redshift to BigQuery?
Thank you

Comment: You only want to copy data or do you have complex transformations and business rules to apply ?

Comment: Only want to copy data. There is no complex transformation. How migration process copy data from Redshift to BigQuery? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery itself supports such use case: [Migrate schema and data from Amazon Redshift](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/migration/redshift)

Is there a reason to use Dataflow? I don't see Redshift in the [list of supported IOs by Beam](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/). Probably you can open a feature request or contribute yourself - https://github.com/apache/beam/issues.

Comment: I use dataflow because I will copy 100 tables every day, so I want to using Dataflow. Any alternative besides Dataflow?